# HomePage return to the top as user keep scrolling down the page

Tags: javascript, html, scroll, scrollview, meta-tags

Every time when scrolling down  the pages, I want to stay there and it takes me back up to the top of the page again

It was Okay before until I add The meta tag "refresh" code to direct to the root on windows hosting

```
<meta http-equiv="refresh" content="2; url='http://site.com.au'">
```

How can I make my site to letting users to stay there when scrolling down the pages?

When i remove the meta tag I was allowed to scroll view the page properly without taking me back to the top

I need a meta refresh tag to direct my page to the root directory

Answer (score 0):

On URL remove the Quatation marks from the site links '..'

```
<meta http-equiv="refresh" content="2; url=http://site.com.au">
```